# Rails Vim tab completition for model and controller works different than for views

Tags: autocompletion, filetype-ruby

I'm using Vim with Rails Vim plugin. When trying to tab-complete command `:Emodel U` or `:Econtroller U` and then `<Tab>` it won't recognize the `user.rb` or `user_controller.rb` file. But works fine for `:Eviews`.

Typing `:verbose command Eview` gives me:

```
Eview * customlist :execute s:viewEdit("<mods> E<bang>",<f-args>)
```

and for `:verbose command Emodel` it prints

```
Emodel * customlist :execute s:CommandEdit('<mods> E<bang>','model',[{'pattern': 'app/models/*.rb', 'affinity': 'model'}],<f-args>)
```

Typing `:Emodel!<Tab>` or any of MVC with `!` will allow me to search through existing files in folder. How can I change it so all MVC modes work the same way?

Comment: Somewhat duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/60361162/9447571, though this one is more focused than that one.

Comment: Can you try to add plug-in [tpope/vim-projectionist](https://github.com/tpope/vim-projectionist) and see if that fixes it? From looking at the code, looks like vim-rails can benefit from integration with vim-projectionist...

Comment: @filbranden "Somewhat duplicate of stackoverflow.com/q/60361162/9447571" - yes that's my question overthere, but meanwhile I've managed to narrow focus on problem thanks to you. I will close it in both places if tpope/vim-projectionist works...

Comment: If projectionist fixes this, feel free to self-reply, that works better!

Comment: Does `:echo b:rails_root` show you the root directory of your Rails project? Do you have an `app/models/` directory there? Do you have `*.rb` files under it? Can you try `:Emodel`, space, Ctrl-D to see if it lists anything? Does it work if you start Vim at the root of the project rather than in a subdirectory (assuming you're not already doing so)?

Comment: Please also try `:echo rails#app().relglob('app/models/', '**/*', '.rb')`, this is what *should* be happening under the hood to produce the completion list. If you want to see the Ruby names, then `:echo map(rails#app().relglob('app/models/', '**/*', '.rb'), 'rails#camelize(v:val)')`

Answer (score 1):

I've finally uninstalled and then again installed tpope/vim-rails and also tpope/vim-projectionist. That fixed the problem. I've deleted question stackoverflow.com/q/60361162/9447571.